# Android cannot get app to read file

Tags: android

I'm having the following problem. I've created a new version of an app that requires to read a file (that exists). Partial logcat output:

> W/System.err: File /storage/emulated/0/ccrypt/data.aux exists.

Also here is the code that prints this:

```
    System.err.println("File " + dataFile + " exists.");
    System.err.println("R: " + file.canRead() + ". W: " + file.canWrite());
    file.setReadable(true);
    file.setWritable(true);
    System.err.println("R: " + file.canRead() + ". W: " + file.canWrite());
```

The problem is that the output from the above code is:

> W/System.err: R: false. W: false
>     W/System.err: R: false. W: false

So whenever I try to read it, I get the permission denied error. I have added these two lines at the bottom of my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What could be the problem? Why am I not able to read/write the file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: Thank you. I'll try the solution in that answer